# Minimize function

Tags: python, math, scipy

I have lists of values Y and X and I want to minimize this function 
[image]

And if necessary, i have start values ​​of Theta, from which function can start search (0.01604 = Theta2,  1.143 = Theta1,  1.537 = Theta0)

I realize Huber function

```
def Huber(l,delta):

    if m.fabs(l)<=delta:
        return 1/2*(l)**2
    else:
        return delta*m.fabs(l)-1/2*delta**2
```

Then I try

```
def my_function(start, X, y):
    Theta0, Theta1, Theta2 = start
    u = Huber((y - (Theta0 + Theta1*X+Theta2*X*X)),7)
    return u

optimized = minimize(my_function(start, X, y), start)
```

And have

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

How to make it right?

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: Are you sure you placed the square in the right place? This function has no minimum.

Comment: what do you mean by "staring points"?  Are thetas constant?  Or are you trying to find thetas which would minimize the value of the function on the left of the arrow?  It's not clear from this notation.

Comment: @rusu_ro1 I didnt try it because I cant understand how to use scipy.minimize for function with some variables(more than 1)

Comment: @grovkin I want to find thetas

Comment: X and Y are constants and i have it

Comment: then @amitavory is right.  you can add $Y_i$, $X_i$ and ${X_i}^2$ first (expand the sum into 4 sums).  So unless the square is outside the 1st or 2nd parenthesis, this is will become A-theata0-theta1*B-theta2*C.  Which has no minimum.

Comment: @grovkin I made a mistake in formula. It should be sum of Huber function, that has an argumet = (Yi - (Theta0...)). It should has minimun. How to find it?

Comment: Please make it clear in your main question just what the function is that is to be minimized. Many of us (including me) know minimization but do not know the "Huber function." The function you show now has no minimum.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Ok, Im sorry i will try make it more clear

Answer (score 3):

Just provide a list with your starting point:

```py
start = [1.537, 1.143, 0.01604]
```

And then use SciPy's `optimize` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)):

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def my_function(args):
    Theta0, Theta1, Theta2 = args
    # here return the value of the function

optimized = minimize(my_function, start)
```

In the above, `Theta0`, `Theta1` and `Theta2` are the variables. It is not clear from the question if they are constants. If that's the case, just use the above code as template and unpack your starting point to the variables, e.g.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

start = [1, 1]

def my_function(args):
    X, y = args # Thetas constant
    # here return the value of the function

optimized = minimize(my_function, start)
```

Note: You should pass the function's name only, not a function call, i.e.

```
minimize(my_function, start) # works
minimize(my_function(....), start) # doesn't work
```

Comment: In this case I have TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable. I updated question and add code that i try

Comment: @ИльшатМурзурбеков you should pass the function's name, not a call. I've updated the answer. And the function should have a single parameter which is the variables to optimise for.